# Hybris hotfolder import by FTP does not create cronjob

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud, hotfolder

When I send file by FTP to hotfolder path directly, import cronjob cannot be created. It moves to the file to archive folder as it is successfully imported.
I can see it triggered CleanupTask without creating impex import cronjob.

```
Setting tenant <<master>> on the current thread Thread[task-scheduler-7,5,main]
Processed CustomHeaderInitTask.execute [header=de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.dataimport.batch.BatchHeader@306f39fd[file=/app/hybris_commerce/hybris/data/acceleratorservices/import/master/apparel/product/processing/hotfolderFileName-jp-en-202212150552.csv,catalog=catalogName,language=ja_JP,net=false]] in 4ms
Setting tenant <<master>> on the current thread Thread[task-scheduler-7,5,main]
Processed ImpexTransformerTask.execute [header=de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.dataimport.batch.BatchHeader@306f39fd[file=/app/hybris_commerce/hybris/data/acceleratorservices/import/master/apparel/product/processing/hotfolderFileName-jp-en-202212150552.csv,catalog=catalogName,language=en,net=false]] in 4ms
Setting tenant <<master>> on the current thread Thread[task-scheduler-7,5,main]
Processed HotFolderImpexRunnerTask$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$af2492be.execute [header=de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.dataimport.batch.BatchHeader@306f39fd[file=/app/hybris_commerce/hybris/data/acceleratorservices/import/master/apparel/product/processing/hotfolderFileName-jp-en-202212150552.csv,catalog=catalogName,language=en,net=false]] in 0ms
Setting tenant <<master>> on the current thread Thread[task-scheduler-7,5,main]
Processed CleanupTask.execute [header=de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.dataimport.batch.BatchHeader@306f39fd[file=/app/hybris_commerce/hybris/data/acceleratorservices/import/master/apparel/product/processing/hotfolderFileName-jp-en-202212150552.csv,catalog=catalogName,language=en,net=false]] in 1ms
```

But if I send file to FTP user's home folder and copy it via `cp` command to the hotfolder path, it imports successfully. It creates cronjob, I can see changes on backoffice.

What is difference between sending files directly to hotfolder path and copying them in the server by command? Also, I tried another environment, it works as expected even if I send it directly to the hotfolder path by FTP.

Comment: Question: After the file is moved to archive folder, do you see new items being created, based on what is in the file? I'm just wondering if the items were created, but there's just no logs for them.

Comment: Did the user of the FTP & user running hybris is on the same group?

Comment: @Adiputera they are in different groups. But I am using the same account while connecting by ssh and running `cp` command

Comment: @geffchang No, items are not created if I send the file directly to the hotfolder path. I am checking on backoffice

Comment: @ozkancinar can you check if the hybris user does have permission to read and write to files uploaded by the FTP user?